# Remotely submitting jobs to a kerberized Hadoop MRv2/YARN cluster

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

First of all, I've seen this is a recurrent question on stackoverflow, for instance:

[Not able to run Hadoop job remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22191568/not-able-to-run-hadoop-job-remotely)

[Running Hadoop Job Remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22231904/running-hadoop-job-remotely)

[Exception while submitting a mapreduce job from remote system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19636220/exception-while-submitting-a-mapreduce-job-from-remote-system)

[Running java hadoop job on local/remote cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612347/running-java-hadoop-job-on-local-remote-cluster)

Nevertheless, I've not seet yet a complete example about how to remotely submit a job:

- When the remote cluster uses MRv2/YARN
- And it is kerberized

Ii must be said such a cluser works perfectly when submitting jobs by means of the `yarn` command (previously getting the Kerberos TGT by using `kinit`).

Regarding the first issue, I've seen the code for a MRv1 job is something like:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://" + host + ":8020");
conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "hdfs://" + host + ":8021");
Job job = new Job(conf, "job-name");
job.setJarByClass(Main.class);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Nevertheless, when using MRv2/YARN there is no Jobtracker. Googling a bit I've seen part of the changes must be made in order the above code works with YARN; specifically:

```
// instead of conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "hdfs://" + host + ":8021");
conf.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "host:9001");
```

Is that right? What else is needed? Is still needed the `conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://" + host + ":8020");` configuration part? What about setting the `hadoop.job.ugi`?

I've also seen that it is possible to put the `core-default.xml` and the `core-site.xml` files in the classpath in order their properties are loaded (as stated in the [`Configuration`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) javadoc). Is this just an alternative to the programmatically settings of the code above, or are both things necessary?

Regarding the second issue, Kerberos, I've seen it is necessary to perform a privileged action, but how does that code look like? I've tried something like:

```
final Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("...", "..."); // the settings below
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createProxyUser("user1", UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser());
ugi.setAuthenticationMethod(AuthenticationMethod.KERBEROS);
ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void run() throws Exception {
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "job-name");
        ...
    }
});
```

But it is not working since I think I have to fix the remote submission part first.

Any hints would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: were you able to get any success with this? I am also facing the same issue on HDP 2.3